# Looking for a springy thin wire to make earrings with

Tags: jewelry, wire

I'm looking for a very thin wire (slightly thicker than fuse wire), that is flexible, but still able to be twisted together. These earrings are for figurines, that are held together and pushed into a hole, and slightly spring open so they do not fall out.

I have researched piano wire, guitar wire, wire wrapping wire and others - but I don't want to spend a lot of money just to find the right product. The full length of the earring in the picture is only about 3.5cm.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Flexible Wire Earring]

Answer (score 6):

The look of it strongly reminds me of christmas tree balls. They even work according to the same principle.

Maybe you have some old christmas tree balls you don't like anymore or one that's broken. Pull the cap out and remove the wire from the rest of the cap.

Comment: That is a great idea, Elmy! I will search some out :) Thank you

Comment: I noticed that there are currently easter decorations on sale that have the same kind of fixtures. Maybe you don't have to sacrifice a christmas ball if you find such an easter egg ball for cheap ;)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I will have a look today. Wouldn't it be terrible if they all came with chocolate. I would just have to eat it! ;)